# Javascript Promise within Class

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Fun with promises today ... I'm trying to figure out why I can't refer to *this.promise* to resolve it with another method, it's always null.

Any enlightenment is appreciated :)

```
export default class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.promise = null
  }

  test() {
    this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.something()
    }).then(resolve => {
      // resolved, do something else
    }).catch(reject => {
      console.log('reject', reject)
    })
  }

  something() {
    this.promise.resolve()
  }
}
```

Comment: [Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) is a static method, not an instance method. Trying to call `resolve` will cause an issue. If you even try in your browser tools to do `const promise = new Promise(resolve => resolve('foobar'))`, what does `promise.resolve` output? Maybe instead in `something()` you are actually I guess you can pass `resolve` to `something` as an argument technically, but you can always just return a promise inside that first `then()`, as in return a promise from `something()`.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `this.promise` in `something` before it's value changes from `null`. Another way to do this is to pass the `resolve` as an argument:

```js
class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.promise = null;
  }
  test() {
    this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.something(resolve);
    }).then(result => {
      console.log('resolve', result);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('reject', error);
    });
  }
  something(resolve) {
    resolve(1);
  }
}
const example = new Example();
example.test();
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, got my head around it now :)